# Service Worker Login Page

Tags: php, caching, authentication, service-worker

I'm having a problem with implementing a service worker cache on a web app that has a login page.

What happens is, the user logs in, service worker installs and activates but then when the user clicks a link, it takes them back to the login page even though they're already logged in!

Can anyone point me in the right direction to a work around?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you probably made wrong is trying to cache a page that needs user permission before the user was logged in. So what happens is: the browser tries to retrieve a route, but the server gives the login page because the user is not logged in.

What you probably need to do:

1. You wait that your user log into your app.
2. One the user is logged, than you register your Service Worker.
3. To cache the page as a logged user, you have to send the cookies info, [with `credentials: include`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials). It will be something like this:

```
    /* sw.js */

```
var cacheName = 'yourCacheName-vx.x.x';

// The route for which you need to be logged in. It's a Request Object.
var appRequest = new Request('/da-private-route', { credentials: 'include' });

var urlsToCache = [
    appRequest, // you add it to your things to cache
    '/manifest.json',
    '/css/styles.css',
    '/js/scripts.js',    
    // other resources…
];

// Installation.
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    e.waitUntil(
        self.skipWaiting().then(function() {
            caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
                return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
            })
        })
    );
});

/* [continue your sw…] */
```

```